# is sbs 2011 really able to handle 50 users?

Tags: windows-sbs-2011

I'm wondering if somebody in here has ever installed/used sbs 2011 with around 50 users (with exchange mailboxes from 1Gb to 6gb, average 2Gb)... No additional LOB apps installed on the server.
I know it can theorically support 75 users but I quite doubt about it.
This question arises as licences total cost for 50 users on sbs 2011 would be around $3000 and licences for the full products (2x w2k8 + 1x exch 2010 + 50 win CALS + 50 exch CALS) would reach 4 times this budget.
Any comments are welcome... I've been a big fan of sbs since 2003 version but I have the feeling it's time to move on to 'real' servers for such amount of users.
Some hardware specs would be welcome too !

Comment: The software can certainly should be able handle it if sufficient hardware is provided.

Answer (score 2):

SBS will easily support **thousands** of users if you give it decent hardware. This is **entirely** a  licensing limitation.  SBS already includes your server and exchange licenses, but you will still need CALs.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutley. 
I've got clients that size running on IBM x3200 servers, 4 core 2.66Ghz, 12GB ram, SAS Drives.

Your mileage may vary, i.e. work load etc. but the server specs I'm running are fairly low end and not having any performance issues.